# Cannot create a package using OpenCV dependencies in ROS Groovy

Tags: opencv, ros

I want to follow the tutorials presented in http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials but I am getting the following error message:

```
~/catkin_ws/src$ roscreate-pkg learning_image_transport image_transport opencv2 cv_bridge
ERROR: dependency [opencv2] cannot be found
```

I am using ROS Groovy in Ubuntu 12.10. I am new to ROS so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roscreate-pkg` will build a `rosbuild` package.

You need to create a `catkin` one with `catkin_create_pkg`.

Have a look at this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage).